# What is the difference between the Bell 412 and the Bell CH-146 Griffon?

Tags: helicopter

What is the difference between the [Bell 412](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_412) and the [Bell CH-146 Griffon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_CH-146_Griffon)?

Comment: Have you tried [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_CH-146_Griffon)?

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, the CH-146 [is a Bell 412EP](http://www.militaryfactory.com/aircraft/detail.asp?aircraft_id=1259), which you can still [buy from Bell today](http://www.bellhelicopter.com/commercial/bell-412ep).

Some features on the CH-146 you won't find on civilian counterparts:

- Weapons.  The CH-146 has attachment points for weapon mounts that aren't typically found on the Bell 412.
- Wescam T-16D-A Thermal Imaging System. This wasn't a production addition to the CH-146, but it appears be common on these helicopters.  Similar aftermarket systems might be in use on Bell 412s in police use.
- Wire Strike Protection System - some civilian helicopters do have this, but they're particularly common on the CH-146 and other military helicopters.
- A Canadian Forces paint job.